# Can you view Internet search history from the hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

How can you see search history once it has been deleted from Internet Explorer or other browsers?

I know there must be a way to view old search history that is still burned on my hard drive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to run your favourite un-deleter on the temp folders that IE uses to get back the history and cache files. Even if the history file is long gone, the browser temporary cache files can be sifted through one by one (or by a script) to extract keywords from the rendered pages.

Comment: Which showed why one of our shop managers was so extremely busy with so little profit. One of his underlings kind of got tired of the situation. Evidence eliminators often don't. They're often created by Trust-a-Crook, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Internet Explorer browsing history in the history "index.dat" file, [you will need software](http://filext.com/faq/open_dat_file.php) to read the contents of the dat file.

This is a permanent record of browsing history for IE, it is normally a hidden file and is not easy to delete.

Depending on the OS where these dat files are stored.

Other browser history (chrome, firefox) may not be recoverable.